# Gnome Terminal Duplication

Tags: session, terminal, gnome

Very often I need two gnome-terminal sessions at the same location.  Is it possible to open a single terminal, get to the directory I need, and make a duplicate of the terminal so I don't have to type in the cd command (which can get lengthy) a second time in the second window?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to your directory of choice, then you have some alternatives:

1. 'gnome-terminal' will open new terminal in that directory
2. New tab will open new tab in same directory
3. You can start a new GNU Screen session based in this directory.

Comment: The second option is not currently working, since default behavior changed in gnome-terminal: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=697475 -- (but no resolution yet... has anyone got a good workaround?)

Comment: There's a simple workaround here: http://superuser.com/questions/596764/how-to-change-gnome-terminals-startup-directory/624073 .

Comment: @petrelharp The second option _is_ working. The link you pointed to is incorrectly marked wontfix whereas the correct one would be incorrect configuration on the user's side. One tiny bit of action needs to be done for new terminals, namely sourcing `/etc/profile.d/vte.sh` from your `.bashrc`. If you installed gnome-terminal for yourself, you need to do this. If you're using a distribution which doesn't configure this, you should ask them to fix this. Also, the "workaround" link is not a workaround, but a description of the proper way of setting this up.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you have a gnome-terminal open, opening a new tab (i.e. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd>) will open a new tab in the same directory you're in when you make the tab.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>N</kbd> does the same thing but opens a different window.

Comment: It opens to your home directory, not the current working directory.

Comment: @Jeroen in that case something's not configured properly on your system. Assuming gnome-terminal >= 3.8, you should source `/etc/profile.d/vte.sh` from your `.bashrc` which sets up the necessary hook.

Answer (score 1):

For Bash and Z shell, add this to your shell's rc file (that is, `~/.bashrc` or `/.zshrc`):

```sh
source /etc/profile.d/vte.sh
```

(This solution is promoted from comments to other answers.)

Answer (score 0):

consider doing this in the active directory you already in press **F4**

by default this will open a new terminal with the relative path you are in